# Slimmest possible mini-ITX setup with a decent GPU

Tags: graphics-cards, mini-pc

I'm building a **slim** PC around a mini ITX motherboard, which should pack enough CUDA power with a low price. I came into the conclusion that GTX 750 Ti is a good choice (OK performance, low price, low heat generation).

The slimness I plan to achieve using a 90 degree PCI-e riser card (similar to http://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-Express-16x-Riser-Card-90-degree-Right-angle-4cm-Adapter-Card-2U-/170914230015)

However, the problem is that I don't know if the GPU will fit a specific motherboard with a specific CPU cooler and if the RAM modules will interfere. Is the 750 Ti a reasonable choice and is there a difference between different manufacturers? Or should I look into some slimmer options? I am building a custom case, so PSU and SSD can be placed anywhere, even outside the motherboard's area.

Comment: There are two types of 90-degree riser cards differing in which way they bend: over-the-board risers, and traditional risers.  If you're concerned about overall volume, an over-the-board riser permits a smaller case; a traditional riser permits a thinner case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my own question is Silverstone RVZ01 with only 10.5 cm height.
http://www.silverstonetek.com/raven/products/index.php?model=RVZ01

They include a custom 90 degree riser inside the case, which should fit most GPUs.